# how to use float in list slicing when use round()

Tags: python-2.7

I practice list slicing, but I have some error.

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11]
print li[:int(len(li)*0.3)]
print li[int(len(li)*0.3):]
```

It will print  [1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

but when i use `round()`, it goes wrong. How do I solve it?

```
li[:(round(li)*0.3)]
```

----> 1 `li[:(round(li)*0.3)]`

`TypeError: a float is required`

First, I try to add a `float`

```
float (li[:(round(li)*0.3)])
```

but there is still an error

Comment: Did you mean `li[:round(len(li)*0.3)]`? You're currently trying to round *the list itself*...

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to carry the `len()` function call:

```
li[:round(len(li)*0.3)]
```

But, this would result into the `slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method` error. You should convert the rounded boundary value to an integer:

```
li[:int(round(len(li)*0.3))]
```

Comment: I assume they want the product *inside* the rounding, as written it's a `TypeError`.

Comment: yes,when i use you code , it still tell me TypeError